# SAPUI5 DatePicker minDate not working

Tags: javascript, date, sapui5

I am trying to add an inline minDate on a datePicker in SAPUI5.

I have tried:

**Fragment**

`<DatePicker id="PurchaseDateFromId" value="" minDate="{ new Date(); }"/>`

`<DatePicker id="PurchaseDateFromId" value="" minDate="{ todayDate }"/>`

**Controller**

`var todayDate = new Date();`

Neither work and the console states that it must be a JS object.

Comment: Did these examples help you and is the question closed?

Comment: Thanks they did help but did not solve it.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: The issue has been solved, I'll write it up when I get time. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe these examples help you out.

**View 1**

```
<DatePicker minDate="{dateModel>/minDate}" />
```

**Controller 1**

```
    onInit: function() {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel( {
            minDate: new Date()
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "dateModel");
    }
```

**View 2**

```
<DatePicker id="PurchaseDateFromId"/>
```

**Controller 2**

```
onInit: function() {
            this.byId("PurchaseDateFromId").setMinDate(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting `maxDate` and `minDate` properties of `sap.m.DatePicker` after loading *fragment* in *controller*.

**Controller**

```
//Fragment loaded 
var oPurchaseDt = this.getView().byId("PurchaseDateFromId");
if (oPurchaseDt) {
   var oPurchaseMaxDate = '';//update max date
   var oPurchaseMinDate = new Date();
   oPurchaseDt.setMaxDate(oPurchaseMaxDate);
   oPurchaseDt.setMinDate(oPurchaseMinDate);
}....
```

**Fragment**

```
<DatePicker id="PurchaseDateFromId" value=""/>
```

Note: If the `maxDate` is set to be before the `minDate`, the `maxDate` and the `minDate` are switched before rendering.